# Why I can't add more than one Object to the JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

When I add to the GameScreen more than one Object of class Duck only one appears on the screen. When I add Duck outside constructor in GameScreen class I have many Object of Duck but then the mouseClicked method doesn't work on Duck.

Comment: Take a look at [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html). `BorderLayout` will only present the last component added to any single position. Having said that, I don't think this is the direction you really want to head in. Instead, start with a single `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent` method, then render all you game objects directly through. Components are heavy objects with a lot of complexity and aren't generally well suited for this kind of operation

Comment: You also don't need 3+ threads (Swing `Timer`s make use of a thread to schedule calls back to the UI).  Use a single Swing `Timer` as your "main game loop", which should be responsible for updating the state and scheduling paint passes.  Swing is not thread safe, so the use of the `Thread`  to update the label is ill advisied

Comment: Thank you for your advice and actually removing BorderLayout worked.

Comment: But when I try to add Ducks to the JPanel in GameScreen use paintComponent they doesn't appear.

Comment: Don’t use components for your game entities

Comment: Can you explain me how I can add this duck more specific?

Comment: `Graphics#drawImage` would be the starting point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html). `BorderLayout` will only present the last component added to any single position.

Having said that, I don't think this is the direction you really want to head in. Instead, start with a single `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent` method, then render all you game objects directly through. Components are heavy objects with a lot of complexity and aren't generally well suited for this kind of operation.

Also, you also don't need 3+ threads (Swing `Timer`s make use of a thread to schedule calls back to the UI). Use a single Swing `Timer` as your "main game loop", which should be responsible for updating the state and scheduling paint passes. Swing is not thread safe, so the use of the `Thread` to update the label is ill advised.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/Duck.png"));
                    List<Duck> ducks = new ArrayList<>();
                    ducks.add(new Duck(img));
                    ducks.add(new Duck(img));

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(new GamePane(ducks));
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class Duck {
        private BufferedImage image;

        private int x;
        private int y;

        private int xDelta = 0;
        private int yDelta = 0;

        public Duck(BufferedImage image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        public BufferedImage getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public void setLocation(int x, int y) {
            setX(x);
            setY(y);
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int getWidth() {
            return image == null ? 0 : image.getWidth();
        }

        public int getHeight() {
            return image == null ? 0 : image.getHeight();
        }

        public void setDelta(int x, int y) {
            xDelta = x;
            yDelta = y;
        }

        public int getXDelta() {
            return xDelta;
        }

        public int getYDelta() {
            return yDelta;
        }

        public void move(Rectangle bounds) {
            int xDelta = getXDelta();
            int yDelta = getYDelta();
            int x = getX() + xDelta;
            int y = getY() + yDelta;

            if (x < bounds.x) {
                x = bounds.x;
                xDelta *= -1;
            } else if (x + getWidth() >= bounds.x + bounds.width) {
                x = (bounds.x + bounds.width) - getWidth();
                xDelta *= -1;
            }

            if (y < bounds.y) {
                y = bounds.y;
                yDelta *= -1;
            } else if (y + getWidth() >= bounds.y + bounds.height) {
                y = (bounds.y + bounds.height) - getHeight();
                yDelta *= -1;
            }
            setDelta(xDelta, yDelta);
            setLocation(x, y);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics2D g2d, ImageObserver observer) {
            g2d.drawImage(getImage(), getX(), getY(), observer);
        }
    }

    public class GamePane extends JPanel {
        private List<Duck> ducks;

        public GamePane(List<Duck> ducks) {
            this.ducks = ducks;

            Random rnd = new Random();

            for (Duck duck : ducks) {
                int width = 400 - duck.getWidth();
                int height = 400 - duck.getHeight();

                int x = rnd.nextInt(width);
                int y = rnd.nextInt(height);

                int xDelta = rnd.nextBoolean() ? 1 : -1;
                int yDelta = rnd.nextBoolean() ? 1 : -1;

                duck.setLocation(x, y);
                duck.setDelta(xDelta, yDelta);
            }

            Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(getSize());
                    for (Duck duck : ducks) {
                        duck.move(bounds);
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            for (Duck duck : ducks) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                duck.paint(g2d, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From this, you can start adding more entities as needed, for example, I can modify the `Main` method to include LOTs of ducks...

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/Duck.png"));
List<Duck> ducks = new ArrayList<>(100);
for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
    ducks.add(new Duck(img));
}
```

This is obviously and overly simplified example intended only as a demonstration of core concept, you'll need to do more research into basic game development and 2D graphics.

Comment: Thank you very much, everything works as it should, but I have one more question because I can't add the class duck mouseListener or ActionListener because I need to be able to click the duck. I try in my all class where I have object of Duck but it doesnt work. Do you know why? is it related to the fact that the picture is moving?

Comment: So, the `Duck` has a concept of location and size, from this you can do basic "hit detection" directly from `GamePane` (on which you should register the `mouseListener`).  Personally, I make use [`Rectangle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Rectangle.html) as it has handy methods to this for you