# Java Swing: how to react to clicking a custom JComponent?

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I'm trying to make a game with ducks, the ducks are moving on the screen and I can't get a mouse click on them. I'm obviously doing something wrong because despite setting a MouseListener, its methods are not called. This is my code, I omitted getters and the DuckGame class, which is only generating ducks.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class DuckGameScreen extends JPanel {
    private int initialDuckNum = 7;
    private final int INTERVAL = 25;
    private final int INTERVAL_BTWN_DUCKS = 1000;
    private Timer duckTimer;
    private int ducksStarted = 0;
    private DuckGame duckGame;


    public DuckGameScreen() {
        setBackground(Color.cyan);
        askAboutDifficulty();
        startTimer();
        startGame();
        startDifficultyIncrease();
    }

    private void startGame() {
        duckGame = new DuckGame(initialDuckNum);
        startDucks();
        addDuckListeners();
    }

    private void addDuckListeners() {
        for (Duck duck : duckGame.getDucks()) {
            duck.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Duck clicked");}

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        drawDucks(g);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    }

    private void animateDuck(Duck duck) {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                while (!duck.isDuckStopped()) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
                        duck.move();
                        if (duck.getX() - duck.getWidth() >= Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width) {
                            duck.resetPosition();
                        }
                        repaint();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        duck.stop();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
                .start();
    }

    private void drawDucks(Graphics g) {
        for (Duck duck : duckGame.getDucks()) {
            duck.paintComponent(g);
        }
    }
}
```

And my Duck class:

```
public class Duck extends JComponent {
    private final static int INIT_X = -100;
    private int x = INIT_X;
    private int y = 100;
    private int width = 0;
    private int height = 0;
    private Image image = null;
    private boolean isDuckStopped = false;
    private final int STEP = 5;

    public Duck() {
        initRandomPosition();
        loadImage();
        setVisible(true);
        setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    }

    private void initRandomPosition() {
        y = getRandomY();
    }

    public void move() {
        x += STEP;
    }

    private void loadImage() {
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(getFilePath(Images.DUCK.getFileName()));
        Dimension newDimension = Utils.getScaledDimension(100, 100, imageIcon.getIconWidth(), imageIcon.getIconHeight());
        image = imageIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(newDimension.width, newDimension.height, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        width = image.getWidth(null);
        height = image.getHeight(null);
    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        drawDuck(g);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    }

    private void drawDuck(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2D.drawImage(image, x, y, this);
        setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public void stop() {
        isDuckStopped = true;
        setVisible(false);
    }

    public void resetPosition() {
        x = INIT_X;
        y = getRandomY();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post a proper [mre]. That is create a JFrame with a JPanel using a FlowLayout. Then create a single Duck object and add it to the panel. Get the MouseListener working on the single duck. Once that works THEN AND ONLY THEN do you worry about adding multiple ducks to your game. It is easier to debug a simple application so make sure it works for a single duck first. Also, images are NOT needed to test this. you can simple paint the background of your component to show its size/location. The game animation is also unnecessary.

Comment: Honestly, I would recommend not doing it this way. Components aren't meant for this kind of work and carry a lot of overhead.  For example, your `Duck` is storing the x/y and width/height properties, but components already have a concept of position and size, so this is not only confusing, it's also redundant and potential a source of issues. And you appear not to be the only person doing this - for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72355026/why-i-cant-add-more-than-one-object-to-the-jpanel/72370771#72370771)

Comment: I've been using Swing for some 24 years and I've never found the need to use `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();`.  Also, you shouldn't be overriding `paint`, but instead, preferring `paintComponent`; you shouldn't manually be painting components (like you are in `drawDucks`) and in fact you'll probably find that doing something like will prevent things like `MouseLIstener` from working on the components.  Swing is NOT thread safe and is single threaded.  This means that you shouldn't update the UI or any state the UI relies from outside the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details and [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for the most probable solution

Comment: And you should probably also have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: Look, I've been learning Swing for a week and I have a deadline today for this project. Could you please tell me more about what to do and not what not to do? If storing these values is not right, how should I do it? I only followed a tutorial here: https://zetcode.com/javagames/animation/. And also, paintComponent isn't working for some reason and I found paint is so I used it. And if I add Duck to my panel, it's not working either so... I clearly need help with this.